# Script attached to one button triggers other buttons too in unity

Tags: c#, unity

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I have 4 buttons.

I have attached a C# script to only one button to change the scene on click.

Now the scene should change only when I click on the button to which I have attached the script.

But the scene changes even if I click anywhere else on the screen.

This is the script that I have attached -

```
public class ButnDoSmthng : MonoBehaviour {

        void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))       
            Application.LoadLevel ("Scene1");       
    }   
}
```

Whats wrong here and what might be a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) will return true whenever mouse button `0` is pressed, no matter if the mouse is only pressed over the object that has that code in it's script.

You might be thinking, instead of [`Update`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) to use [`OnMouseDown()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), which only activates when that object's collider is clicked. But, you'd still being using Unity's buttons wrong.

What you need to do is a create a public `SceneChange` method, doesn't even have to be in a script attached to your button, just somewhere in the scene, perhaps on a `GameManager` object. Then is that `OnClick` event that's in your Button properties:

[image]

Under `Runtime` where it currently says `Button`, select the object that's holding the script with your `SceneChange` method. Then the drop down to the right will populate with a list of scripts, and sublists of their public methods. Select your `SceneChange` method from that drop down.

Now when your button is clicked, it'll fire an event which will trigger your `SceneChange` method, and it'll only be from the button you choose.

See [this tutorial from Unity](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button) for a walkthrough of how to create these methods.